# Clone Windows 10 to SSD from dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

I'm planning to migrate from HDD to SSD. I have dual boot windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my HDD. I want to clone my windows (only) to SSD so that I can boot from SSD. But if I do so, what will happen to my Ubuntu? Am I able to see grub window to select my OS? And How do I change my boot order ?

Comment: Which tool will you use to clone the HDD to SSD? If you're using a semi-pro tool like Macrium Reflect, then you shouldn't have any issues. If you're using a "free" application, then you may run into alignment issues. Do yourself a favour and investigate which tools would be best to move from HDD to SSD, because there are distinct differences between the technologies that need to be taken into account and written to the new partition tables ...

Comment: There are no "free" tools that I know of that will reliably clone partitions from HDD to SSD, taking into account the differences in data structure, updating the partition metadata, and synchronising the blocks. If this is not something you're willing to invest any money on, perhaps it would be better to simply install a fresh copy of Windows, then Ubuntu, then copy your files from the old disk over to the SSD. From there you can format the HDD and use it as slow-storage or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. I want to clone only the Windows OS partition not the entire disk... I don't want to change anything in my Ubuntu hdd. How can I do it without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way guys... first we need to clone the system ( in my case it's windows 10 ) to the ssd using a free or paid tool. Then we have to log in Ubuntu and update the grub boot loader either by using command line or gui. It will detect our Windows OS on ssd. Then we can choose our OS on grub screen.